# How to add different cell to tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift4

I have a tableview and I'm downloading data from firebase after that I reload tableview but I want to add more different cell to tableview too. For example my datas count is six and I want to add to second row and fifth row different cell. In the end I want to show eight cell.

I tried this code;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "makeLiveWallpaper") as! LiveWallTableViewCell
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Let's make LiveWallpaper"
        }
        return cell
    }else{
        if let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CategoryTableViewCell{
            cell.category = category(at: indexPath)
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setScrollPosition(x: offsets[indexPath] ?? 0)
            return cell
        }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 140
    }else{
        return 255
    }
}
```

But it is not adding new cell it is over write on cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you got the data update your dataSource like given below:

```
data.insert("", at: 1)
data.insert("", at: 4)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

> update your Data Source Method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        // your custom Cell
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 5 {
        // you custom Cell
        return cell
    } else {
        // normal cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Hope it will hep you.

Comment: but data is a struck it says "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Category'"

Comment: @SadiHakan "" is for sample here you have to add your Category object in the array.